# PHP reversing the order of the numbers from right to left and integrating them into a string

Tags: php, string

I have a display for a weight scale.
I need to send following string '000000=.' to serial port display if there is no weight value.

for display I need to reverse order of number:

```
scale weight: 236
display string will be : 632000=.
```

I need a php function to do that- it's is possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible

Comment: `strrev(sprintf('%06d', 236))` – and it’s not that hard to look through the string function overview in the manual – so next time, please do that before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right: [This function revert string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)

```
$input = 1234;
$output = strrev($input);
for ($i = strlen($output); $i < 6; $i++) {
    $output .= '0';
}
$output .= "=.";
```

I think, now, I have understand you right.

Comment: what if I had weight = 1235 ? How can i do to show "532100=."?

Comment: Ok, I understand you problem, just a minute.

Answer (score 2):

```
$input = 236;
$output = str_pad(strrev($input),6,'0').'=.';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php